# 80s movie about man who develops another identity and robs his father in law's bank

Tags: identify-this-movie

There's a movie from the 80s (possibly late 70s) in America where a guy is married to the rich boss' daughter. He's meek and not respected by his wife or father in law. She spends most of her time playing make-believe in various costumes.

Something happens and he develops another identity. I think for part of the movie he just insists that he's a whole other person, rather than just a guy with another personality. He becomes more gruff and forceful. He hires a prostitute to make him better at having sex. His wife eventually falls in love with him because he's forceful with her.

Eventually, he decides to rob his father in law who owns, I think, a bank. Then I think he and his wife run away together? The ending is a bit foggy in my head.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like [*The American Success Company*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0078765/combined) from 1980 that starred Jeff Bridges and Ned Beatty and was written by Larry Cohen. From [Rotten Tomatoes](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/the_american_success_company_2011/):

> The movie tells the story of Harry Flowers (Bridges), a Milquetoast employee of a Munich-based credit card company, AmSucCo (did AmEx raise any eyebrows at that?), married to the daughter (Bauer) of his tyrannical boss (Ned Beatty). Flowers allows himself to be shoved around and coddled by everyone, until he suddenly decides to slip into an assumed identity -- that of a gruff, bull-by-the-horns modern-day prince, determined to "rescue himself" from wimpdom by learning sexual aggression from a prostitute (Bianca Jagger) and ultimately wresting millions from the hand that feeds him

...by robbing his father-in-law's business. Here's a promo [sorry about the quality]:

Comment: @James No problem! :) Don't forget to approve the answer by clicking on the check mark next to it, this effectively resolves your question. And welcome to M&TV!